# Animate the opacity of stars drawn via canvas

Tags: css, reactjs, animation, canvas

How to animate the opacity of stars drawn via canvas? I'm trying to draw multiple stars behind a mountain. So far I can think of 2 options.

1. I can use 2 layers of image, and hiding the stars behind mountain layer, and use css3 keyframe animation on the opacity of the stars.
2. Draw both foreground(mountain ranges) and background(stars) via canvas. This is the approach I'm undertaking right now.

I have 2 issues.

1. Opacity of stars are flipping/blinking extremely fast, and can I add delay between animations? Currently, I'm calling infinite loop `window.requestAnimationFrame(this.animate);` I tried to use `setInterval` but animations aren't as smooth as `requestAnimationFrame`
2. Can I eventually stop this blinking effect?

This is written inside of react component

```js
  // Animation Loop
  animate = () => {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(this.animate);
    this.c.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);

    // fill background
    this.c.fillStyle = this.backgroundGradient;
    this.c.fillRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);

    // createmountainRange
    this.createMountainRange(1, this.canvas.height - 50, "#384551");
    this.createMountainRange(2, this.canvas.height - 150, "#2B3843");
    this.createMountainRange(3, this.canvas.height - 250, "#26333E");

    this.backgroundStars.forEach(backgroundStar => {
      this.draw(backgroundStar);
    });
  };

  //draw function
  draw = star => {

    const opacity = 1 / utils.randomIntFromRange(1, 10);
    this.c.save() // only affects code in between
    this.c.beginPath();
    this.c.arc(star.x, star.y, star.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
    this.c.fillStyle = `rgba(227, 234, 239, ${opacity})`
    this.c.shadowColor = '#e3eaef'
    this.c.shadowBlur = 20
    this.c.fill();
    this.c.closePath();
    this.c.restore()

    console.log('opacity', opacity)
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You could give each star a separate property to indicate when it should recalculate the opacity (which would also be stored in a property), and only change it at those points; You can use basic easing (like `source * (1 - factor) + target * factor`, or look up formulas) to gradually tween between original and new opacity.
2. With above, you would use a condition to stop recalculating alpha once that is no longer needed.

A separate-canvas approach can be used, but only if you want all of your stars to have the exact same alpha at any given point;

You might be able to use `globalAlpha` instead of stitching a new `fillStyle` on every draw, which might also look better for shadows.

Answer (score 0):

Your animation function have a frame parameter you can use with a sin function to add a blinking effect, I need more of your code to check for a precise solution but you can try something like this:

```
  // Animation Loop
  animate = (frame) => {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(this.animate);
    this.c.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);

    // fill background
    this.c.fillStyle = this.backgroundGradient;
    this.c.fillRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);

    // createmountainRange
    this.createMountainRange(1, this.canvas.height - 50, "#384551");
    this.createMountainRange(2, this.canvas.height - 150, "#2B3843");
    this.createMountainRange(3, this.canvas.height - 250, "#26333E");

    this.backgroundStars.forEach((backgroundStar, i) => {
      this.draw(backgroundStar, i, frame || 0);
    });
  };

  //draw function
  draw = (star, index, frame) => {

    const opacity = Math.sin(index * frame * 0.01);
    this.c.save() // only affects code in between
    this.c.beginPath();
    this.c.arc(star.x, star.y, star.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
    this.c.fillStyle = `rgba(227, 234, 239, ${opacity})`
    this.c.shadowColor = '#e3eaef'
    this.c.shadowBlur = 20
    this.c.fill();
    this.c.closePath();
    this.c.restore()

    console.log('opacity', opacity)
  };
```